# One word for one who accepts advice?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I want a word for a person who accepts advice of others.  Basically, I am reading a play and in that there is a ruler who accepts the wise advice of others. What word can be used to describe such a person? Example :

That man is indeed __________ since he imbibes the noble qualities of the wise by the accepting their advices.

Please provide a  reference sentence with your answer.

Comment: Only a wise man listens to other wise men.

Comment: Hello, Abcd. You need to get yourself familiarized with the guidelines of our Help Center. Can you write an example sentence where the word would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please don't ask a question "what is one word for XYZ?". There could be tens of words unless you specify your context with an example sentence. Your question received one close-vote as **primarily opinion-based** and your question doesn't work here.

Comment: @Rathony ...... have I edited properly ?

Comment: Here's [from the Bible](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/12-15.htm): "The way of fools seems right to them, but the wise listen to advice."

Answer (score 1):

"Wise" itself is a great word for this, but it's not as specific as what you're looking for. Perhaps a synonym like "prudent" would do the trick, though.

"Receptive" is a word for someone who is "willing to listen to or accept ideas, suggestions, etc." [(Merriam Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/receptive)

Example usage: She is receptive to criticism. He is a receptive listener who benefits from instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Used in a formal sense there is a word >> advisee: the one who receives advice.

Another, probably more appropriate to what you are looking for is >> heedful: the one who takes heed.

Comment: This would be improved by including a dictionary reference/link for each word definition.